# composer could not scan for classes inside /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/IlluminateQueueClosure.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, laravel-4.2

Basically a fresh git clone of a working repo... 
When I try to composer install I get an error. 
Seems like the laravel folders are not being installed the way composer expects to look for them? I tried updating/installing composer, deleting folders and clearing caches already.

I suspect I need to change composer.json or maybe revert to an older composer?

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "zizaco/confide": "~3.2",
    "zizaco/entrust": "~1.2",
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php" : "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~1.8",
    "way/generators": "~2.6"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

[RuntimeException]

`Could not scan for classes inside "[mysite]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/IlluminateQueueClosure.php" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder`